# Drawing over an image using Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

Can I put a Raphael.js canvas over an `IMG` element? What should I do make this layout work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply position the Raphaël canvas over the top of the image element using normal CSS techniques:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 1px solid #999;
}
#wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then nest your elements like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="myimage.jpg">
    <div id="canvas">  
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a full example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/image.html).

Comment: unfortunately it seems that rendering it over the the of HTML makes it impossible to interact with the things below. I dropped in jQuery and removed the image and added text - the text under the svn is not selectable... http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8051/pictureqy.png

Comment: @cwd [See `pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

z-index:2 or some high number for the raphael "paper" div (aka your raphael canvas... which you refer to by:

var paper = Raphael('somediv', 100, 400)

so just go to your css and at #somediv make sure you put it's z-index lower and then put your text div's z-index higher...