# is there a way to resize an image and have an image map stay in the same place? (html/Javascript/CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dictionary

i am currently making a website that s designed to be a test. It has an image and an image map, i am trying to use JavaScript to get the clients screen size and resize the image to fit the clients screen size but when i do the image map is not were i need it to be. Is there a way to get the image map to stay in the same place with out having to "physically" resize the image in paint or Photoshop. [My site](http://www.sherrimack.com/complit) (with out getting the clients screen size). Basically i am trying to make the image fit their screen so its easier to navigate the test,its realistic, but without screwing up my image map positioning. Any hep would be much appreciated.

```
    `<map name="desktopmap" >
    <area onclick="correct();" shape="rect" coords="1,575,38,597"  href="OS2.html" >  
    </map>
    <img onclick=" wrong('OS2');" src = "../Pic/desktop.png" usemap = "#desktopmap" >`
```

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you can find every answer just my finding the place where the cursor changes to a pointer. Second, it's hard to help with your issue without posting some code.

Comment: i dont think you understood my issue when the image is resized the image map moves. is there a way to get it to not move.<map name="desktopmap" >
  <area onclick="correct();" shape="rect" coords="1,575,38,597"  href="OS2.html" >  
</map>
<img onclick=" wrong('OS2');" src = "../Pic/desktop.png" usemap = "#desktopmap" >

Comment: What you can do is use absolutely positioned divs with percentage-based coordinates and widths and hook your click events into those. Image maps are a bit outdated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making Hard-coded -dimensions with relative values reusable with area -map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201386/making-hard-coded-dimensions-with-relative-values-reusable-with-area-map), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363358/is-possible-create-map-html-area-in-percentage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do instead is use absolutely positioned divs with percentage-based coordinates and dimensions, and hook your click events into those. That should allow your invisible "buttons" to scale nicely with the image. Image maps are a bit outdated and not very flexible.

Example fiddle (updated with correct/wrong functions):

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZLeK/1/

Example new HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img class="bg" src="http://i.imgur.com/WgsCTDj.gif" />
    <div class="box box1"></div>    
</div>
```

Example new CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.bg {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box1 {
    top: 95%;
    left: 0;
    width: 7%;
    height: 5%;
}
```

In the fiddle I also changed your inline Javascript handling to use event handlers, because those attribute handlers are outdated as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may use mediaqueries to rescale/zoom your map .
two experimental test here : http://dabblet.com/gist/5586117 and http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/AJHmt

If you follow this idea, and think of using zoom + javascript instead of mediaquerie to include older browser such as IE ,  beaware of that some version of IE understands both : transform:scale(x); and zoom:X; . make sure you do not aplly twice a rescalling in that case.

Basicly , coords are pixels coordonates, a scaling is the only way, unless you modyfy each values of each coords :)

... not too sure my english is clear/correct enough.