# html map of a graphic does not change with image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't think this can be done, but I am trying it anyway hoping there is a solution!

sample is at www.meetmainstreet.com

I have a graphic representation of main street, and various points on it, on which I have added links using DW CS6 as follows...

```
<img src="streetmap_2.png" alt="Meet Marion North Carolina Main Street" name="mainmap" usemap="#mainmap" id="mainmap">
<map name="mainmap">
<area shape="circle" coords="337,144,12" href="http://youtu.be/WW0-HDOgeh8" alt="Marion Pharmacy">
<area shape="circle" coords="434,184,12" href="http://youtu.be/jipJdPSQCNg" alt="Austin Furniture">
<area shape="circle" coords="511,183,12" href="#">
<area shape="circle" coords="501,136,12" href="http://youtu.be/xqY1TB9Y1L0" alt="Killoughs Music and Loan">
<area shape="circle" coords="705,178,12" href="#">
 </map>
```

The page is built in the twitter Bootstrap2 css style, and when the image resizes automatically to fit a screen size the coords are off. Is there a way that I can do anything about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Juste google "responsive image maps". It's not possible with only HTML+CSS, but you may find a solution fitting your needs.

Comment: Do you have to use image maps? or would you be happy to absolute position some invisible links over the image

Comment: Thanks Bartude, I was googling but couldn;t find the right phrase I reckon to find exactly my issue, will try that one. And no James it doesn't have to be an image map as such. I was trying to avoid haveing lots of pegs on an embedded google map, looking for a more attractive way of doing it, so invisible links would be great

Answer (score 0):

As you understood, there is no possibility with html and css, but maybe you could find solution [is-possible-create-map-html-area-in-percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363358/is-possible-create-map-html-area-in-percentage) in which they speak about a similar problem. Hope this help. :-)