# Can I use something like Raphael.js to draw vectors above the HTML window?

Tags: javascript, html, raphael, vector-graphics

There are a lot of questions regarding drawing on the canvas element and using things like Raphael.js (which is pretty awesome), but I'd like to know if there is a way I can draw some vectors (mostly diagonal lines) above the DOM document rendered in a html doctype webpage.

I haven't done much with the canvas element but I think it might be possible to do something like this with perhaps:

1. getting / monitoring the window size with javascript
2. creating / resizing a canvas element that takes up the whole page
3. somehow setting transparency on the canvas element
4. drawing the vectors that I want

When you use a clear .gif you can't click on or interact with the things underneath it - I would like to still be able to interact with the webpage normally. I would also like scrolling to move up and down the page normally so the vectors would scroll with the DOM elements.

Am I heading in the right direction with this?

How can I draw vectors above the HTML / DOM in a standard webpage?

Comment: Doesn't Raphael.js use SVG not canvas?

Comment: Sorry, my apologies, I have not done much with either, although I tried Googling and searching on SO before posting. Just trying to get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Yes Raphael.js is a wrapper around SVG and VML to draw vectors in a cross browser way. Plus some higher level functions to make drawing easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of Raphael.js drawing on top of text in a div http://raphaeljs.com/spin-spin-spin.html

Some more background on Raphael:

> Raphael draws on an SVG canvas. If you give that a transparent
>   background and position it over the window (z-index), then you can get
>   the appearance you seek.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/raphaeljs/SAPCl_UMNco

Comment: Good enough. This was more helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407333/drawing-over-an-image-using-raphael-js/3463834#comment17744149_3463834